# Twitter bootstrap navbar and dropdown - not resizing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im currently using a dropdown inside of the menu in my navbar. The drop down works fine when the navbar is in high resolution layout.

When operating in the mobile layout the navbar will not resize when the dropdown is selected, that is unless I open the navbar, then close it, then open it again. While doing this, I noticed that the navbar will not slide down on the first opening - which leads me to believe this is related to a JavaScript event.

Edit - Added nav collapse markup for before and after, and pre render. Problem can be reproduced in Bootply using pre-render markup for the nav-collapse div.

Pre-rendered markup:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
    @PageTemplateFeature("Main Navigation")
    <div class="pull-right">
        @PageTemplateFeature("Service Menu")
    </div>
</div>
```

Before re-opening:

```
<div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: 176px;">
```

[image: Before re-opening]

After re-opening:

```
<div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: auto;">
```

[image: After re-opening]

Markup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>
                <a href="/" class="brand"><span style="color: black;"></span>.COM</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="drop_1">Magazine</a>
                            <ul aria-labelledby="drop_1" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/Magazine/Current-Issue" tabindex="-1">Current Issue</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Magazine/Digital-Edition" tabindex="-1">Digital Edition</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/Blog">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="/Sitemap"> Sitemap </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the difference between your images? (beside in don't see "sitebar" on the first)? Your code on http://bootply.com/63417 don't give a problem? Or can you show it? The resizing problem is caused by your custom css may be.

Comment: Adding to @BassJobsen questions, what browser & browser version are you using? Also what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: The bootply with bootstrap 2.3.1, but you can easy switch to an older version. It works on FF en chrome.

Comment: Using bootstrap 2.3.1. Issue occurring on chrome 27, firefox 19, IE10.

The first image shows the blog and sitemap links not fitting in the navbar, the second image shows the navbar resizing correctly. If there are more than 2 links in the Magazine dropdown, they are also clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, the nav-collapse div also needs the collapse class:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    @PageTemplateFeature("Main Navigation")
    <div class="pull-right">
        @PageTemplateFeature("Service Menu")
    </div>
</div>
```

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5671